# Confluence REST API doesnt work: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: rest, api, curl, confluence

I try to use command

```
curl -u username:password \
     -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{"type":"page","title":"new page","ancestors":[{"id":65613}], "space":{"key”:”ownpage”},”body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' \
     http://localhost:8090/confluence/rest/api/content/ \ 
| python -mjson.tool
```

I use admin username and password and create new sub page under page with ID `65613`, space key is correct and URL should be OK. I've also tried with `localhost:8080` but it always returns

> No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Can you try to use `curl` in `--verbose` mode via `curl -v ...` as well together with option `-w '%{http_code}'` to get the HTTP Response Code? It will give a better insight where the call is failing.

Comment: { [7719 bytes data]
* Failed writing body (0 != 6137)
* Failed writing data
* stopped the pause stream!
100 16073    0 15897  100   176  93019   1029 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 93511
* Closing connection 0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 6137)

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-w'
< HTTP/1.1 200